# Jquery Ajax Post To Cakephp Controller

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I am working on web application that uses CakePHP as the back end and JQuery as the front end. In order to communicate with the server, I have already created form and jquery ajax and browser showing ajax sent request value to url in network. Here is what I have right now:

**Problem**

```
I want to display ajax post value into add.ctp which is not showing
```

**Page 1 Where Ajax Is Working**

```
<script type="text/x-javascript">   
$(".hover-star").click(function () {
$("#hover-test").css("color", "#ff6a00");

    var id= $('input[name=starrating]:checked').attr('id');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '<?php echo Router::url(array('controller'=>'Reviews','action'=>'add'));?>',
        cache: false,
        data: "id="+id,
        dataType: 'HTML',
        success: function(result) {
            window.open('/app/webroot/reviews/add/'+id,'_self');

        },      
        error: function (response, desc, exception) {
            // custom error
        }
    });
});   
</script>

<form method="post">
    <input class="hover-star" type="radio" name="starrating" id="1" value="1" title=""/>
    <input class="hover-star" type="radio" name="starrating" id="2" value="3" title=""/>    
    <input class="hover-star" type="radio" name="starrating" id="3" value="3" title=""/>    
</form>
```

**Page 2 where i want to display ajax requested value Add.ctp**

```
<?php echo $this->ratingPost;?>
```

**Reviews Controller Add Function**

```
function add()
{    
    $this->ratingPost= $data = $this->data;
}
```

Comment: @AbrarKhan no error but chrome browser network showing that ajax sent value and no value showing in `add.ctp` file after click on radio button

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there may be a few things going wrong.  First you need to understand that AJAX is going to POST it's data to the URL specified and wait for a response from the server.  The response will be contained in "result."

In this instance it looks like you are POSTing to /reviews/add.  When you do this, your add method will receive the post data and try to render the add.ctp view file.  This entire render is what is returned to your AJAX success "result."  In your add method, you didn't set anything to the view and you didn't return any values so your "result" is empty.

In your AJAX success you are trying to open a new window that is again calling the add method and you are trying to include the parameter "id" which isn't going to do anything with the returned result, only try to run the method again with the given parameter, but your method doesn't ask for any parameters anyway...

If you want a new window to open with an id value from a click, why even use AJAX, just send the id as a parameter to your add method.  Generally I would think AJAX is used to update content on the currently loaded page dynamically. I will highlight the things I am talking about below in your code.

**Your Script**

```
<script type="text/x-javascript">   
  $(".hover-star").click(function () {
    $("#hover-test").css("color", "#ff6a00");
    var id= $('input[name=starrating]:checked').attr('id');

    window.open('/app/webroot/reviews/add/'+id, '_self');
  }
</script>
```

**Your Add Method**

```
public function add($myID=null){
  $this->set('myID', $myID);
}
```

If you are committed to AJAX, you could do it like this by creating a new method to handle the render of the returned AJAX.  I just don't understand the point.  You would also have to limit what you are returning from your AJAX method to URL safe encoding.

**AJAX way**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '<?php echo Router::url(array('controller'=>'Reviews','action'=>'add'));?>',
    cache: false,
    data: "id="+id,
    dataType: 'HTML',
    success: function(result) {
        window.open('** path to new method for rendering view **'+result, '_self');
    },      
    error: function (response, desc, exception) {
        // custom error
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On Page where ajax is working

```
<div id="show"></div>
```

ajax success will be like

```
success: function (result) {
                $("#show").html(result);
                $("#show").show();
            }
```

Comment: value is showing in `<div id="show"></div>` but why value is not showing in `add.ctp` not print or echo in `controller.php` file

Comment: cakephp version is  2.0.13

Comment: In controller to get value in cakePHP
$data=$this->request->data['name'];

Comment: how can return to add ctp and display post value? im actually new in cakephp

Comment: for return to the views 
$this->set('data', $data);

Comment: data to display in add.ctp echo $data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95452/discussion-between-abrar-khan-and-farhan-dharsi).

Comment: how to print data value in add.ctp?